# Dir.glob fails to return a file listing when a path includes [...]

Tags: ruby, file, glob

I am trying to build a list of files in a directory. I have been using Dir.glob to good success, until I found a dir with a [] in it. Now glob returns nothing.

```
[1] pry(main)> Dir.glob '/Users/zach/inst/good folder/*'
=> ["/Users/zach/inst/good folder/output.txt",
"/Users/zach/inst/good folder/output2.txt"]
[2] pry(main)> Dir.glob '/Users/zach/inst/bad [folder]/*'
=> []
```

Note, that both "good"and "bad" folder have the same contents, and ZSH handles it fine.

```
─$ ls '/Users/zach/inst/good folder'
output.txt  output2.txt

-$ ls '/Users/zach/inst/bad [folder]'
output.txt  output2.txt
```

Any ideas of what is going on, and if there is a workaround?

Comment: Try using double quotes or escaping the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dir.glob '/Users/zach/inst/bad \[folder\]/*'
```

Comment: That works, but I am getting the "bad" path from a Dir.glob. So I am passing in a value glob returned to me in the first place. Is there a way to programmatically escape a path before passing it to glob?

Comment: path.gsub!( '[', '\\[').gsub!(']', '\\]') would do it for the square brackets. Do you have any other "bad" characters?

Comment: I guess that is my point :)... I didn't expect [] to be an issue at all. I just found it randomly. Are there any other hidden "bad" characters?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Traverse a directory recursively? Why do you need to use Dir.glob?

Comment: Yes, walk down a dir tree. I don't need glob, just prefer it's syntax. I can allow my users to express a path using glob if they like, and I just traverse from there.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for glob, http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob , or consider using Dir.entries.

Comment: Ahh, of course, [] are also glob commands, which is why they need to be escaped. Thanks.